# Bayes formula measure change

Tags: stochastic-calculus, radon-nikodym

The Bayes formula is

$$E^T\left(\frac{V(T)}{P(T,T)}\right) = \frac{E^Q\left(\frac{dP^T}{dQ}\frac{V(T)}{P(T,T)}\right)}{E^Q\left(\frac{dP^T}{dQ} \right)}$$

I only write $P(T,T)$ to be explicit, it is trivially equal to $1$.

But then I also came across this formula in [Brownian Motiona Calculus](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Brownian-Motion-Calculus-Ubbo-Wiersema/dp/0470021705), page 167:
$$E^T\left(\frac{V(T)}{P(T,T)}\right) = E^Q\left(\frac{dP^T}{dQ}\frac{V(T)}{P(T,T)}\right)$$

Similar relations are used in [Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Arbitrage-Theory-Continuous-Oxford-Finance/dp/0199271267) page 402 and 403.

Could someone please help me reconcile the two equations. Because in the second equation we seem to have ignored the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Radon-Nikodym derivative is a probability density function, so $E^Q[\frac{dP^T}{dQ}]=1.$ The first expression, is the general one because it works also for conditional expectations. The second one doesn't but when $\mathscr{F}_0= \{ \emptyset, \Omega \}$, both formulas agree. The general formula is
$$E^T\left(\frac{V(T)}{P(T,T)}\right) = \frac{E^Q \left[\left(\frac{dP^T}{dQ}\frac{V(T)}{P(T,T)}\right)|\mathscr{F}_t\right]}{E^Q \left[ \left(\frac{dP^T}{dQ} \right)|\mathscr{F}_t \right]}.$$

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by first and second expression? I guessed you meant first and second equations but then you said "The first expression, is the general one" so I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, by first expression I meant your first equation.

Comment: Just for my understanding, in your first line we are assuming that the filtration is as of t=0?

Comment: The first line is just the expected value, it has a definition on its own. But yes, it is true that $E^Q \left[ \left(\frac{dP^T}{dQ} \right) \right] = E^Q \left[ \left(\frac{dP^T}{dQ} \right)|\mathscr{F}_0 \right]$

Comment: Very kind of you to help, thank you.

Comment: you're welcome!